# Orbeon dialog is shown in Chrome 59V but not working in Chrome 60V

Tags: forms, google-chrome, orbeon

We have Orbeon Forms implemented in a project. When we edit an Orbeon dialog is opened to enter some values. It was working successfully with Chrome 59.0.

Last month Chrome browser had an update and updated to version 60.0. The same code for the Orbeon dialog is not showing.

A request sent to Orbeon is successful and getting the response back but not showing in Chrome.

This is working as expected in Internet Explorer and Chrome 59.0.

Comment: Can you show the code you use as it is difficult to see the potential issue unless you do this.

Answer (score 1):

This is a known issue with versions of Orbeon Forms up to 4.4 (from January 2014). You can upgrade to Orbeon Forms PE 4.4.1 or newer to correct the problem. See also [this discussion for steps](http://discuss.orbeon.com/Chrome-60-breaks-Orbeon-3-9-td4662710.html).